# How to extract 24-dimensional color histogram feature vector from an Image with Non overlaped patch size 32 X 32 in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I want to read the image with patch size 32 X 32 Non-Overlapping patches and for each patch should be represented with R, G, B values with 8+8+8 = 24 dimensions of feature vector.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want three 8-bin histograms for each patch, one for each color channel. If your image data are `uint8`, then we can get the appropriate bin index for each pixel by right shifting by five bits. The actual histogramming can be done using `np.bincount` + some mild trickery, to work around its being 1D only.

This is essentially a one-liner. Most of the code below is devoted to dealing with non-multiple-of-32 image dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

def histo24(img):
    h, w, c = img.shape
    assert c == 3
    assert img.dtype == np.uint8
    # pad
    H, W = (h+31)>>5, (w+31)>>5
    patches = np.zeros((H, 32, W, 32, 3), np.uint8)
    patches.reshape(H<<5, W<<5, 3)[:h, :w] = img>>5
    # the next line is the actual histogramming
    histo = np.bincount(
        (patches + np.arange(0, H*W*24, 8).reshape(H, 1, W, 1, 3)).ravel(),
        minlength=H*W*24).reshape(H, W, 24)
    # subtract padded zeros from zero bins at the right and bottom edges
    if h & 31:
        histo[-1, :, ::8] -= (31&-h)<<5
    if w & 31:
        histo[:, -1, ::8] -= (31&-w)<<5
        if h & 31:
            histo[-1, -1, ::8] += (31&-h)*(31&-w)
    return histo
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

Code for example:

```
def visualize(histo):
    h, w, c = histo.shape
    assert c == 24
    vis = np.zeros((h, 32, w, 32, 3), np.uint8)
    idx = np.arange(28)[None, :, None]
    for c in range(3):
        bnds = (histo[..., c<<3:(c+1)<<3].cumsum(axis=-1)*(28/1024)).astype(np.uint8)[..., ::-1]
        for j in range(1, 8):
            view = vis[:, 2:-2, :, 7*c+6:7*c+12, c]
            view[..., 0][(idx >= bnds[:, None, :, j]) &
                         (idx < bnds[:, None, :, j - 1])] = (j<<5)|16
            view[..., 1:] = view[..., :1]
    return vis.reshape(h<<5, w<<5, 3)

from scipy.misc import face
import Image

exmpl = face()
histo = histo24(exmpl)
Image.fromarray(exmpl).show()
#Image.fromarray(exmpl>>5<<5).show()
Image.fromarray(visualize(histo)).show()
```